# A word that means stage-fright, but for a person?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

Suppose you met a famous person, and you were shy and anxious and almost overwhelmed by them.

Is there a word for describing that? Similar to getting stage fright, or "choking", except in this case for a person?

> When he said hello to me, I couldn't respond. I (was) __________.

Comment: When he said hello to me, I couldn't respond. I was revered.

Answer (score 7):

If it is specifically a famous person, you could use [star-struck.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/starstruck)

starstruck

/ˈstɑːstrʌk/

adjective

1.
*completely overawed by someone's celebrity status*

Answer (score 2):

You might be [*overawed:*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overawed)

> **over·awe** *verb*
>
> : to make (someone) unable to think, speak, or behave normally because of a strong feeling of respect and fear

(Definition from Merriam-Webster.com)

Comment: You might also check out *awestruck*.

Comment: @Nick2253, it struck me too. Why not post it as an answer.